# Why doesn't Bane immediately blow up Gotham when he sees the Bat-symbol on fire on the Gotham bridge?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

I've heard of people nitpicking at *The Dark Knight Rises* a lot (continuity errors mostly). But I think I found the clincher.

Why doesn't Bane immediately blow up Gotham when he sees the Bat-Symbol on fire on the Gotham bridge?

So far, I haven't heard an answer that makes sense. Apparently, Bane was OK risking the entire operation of the League of Shadows for no reason, other than he wanted a cool final battle.

Answer (score 2):

Talia had her hand on the 'trigger', not Bane and during the few scenes they shared together it was pretty obvious that he was devoted to her both as a personal friend and as the head of the League, which may have included him not getting any say or opinions across with regards to Bruce's return and the use of the bomb.

The question may be more with regards to 'why didn't Talia blow the bomb up' but, like Bane, perhaps she had her own plan / schedule to stick to including her final attempt at disillusioning Bruce with the reveal of her identity and the whole 'slow knife' idiocy.

Answer (score 0):

He didn't blow it up because he anticipated Batmans return, he wanted good for gotham, he wanted the Dark Knight to rise and defeat him, he never actually planned to blow Gotham up, that's why when the BatJet blew up it barely made an explosion, Bane actually stood for the good of all people and saw Gotham as a sesspit that had a hero in Batman (Bane knew that Bruce Wayne was Batman) that was hiding and letting Gothams scumbag big wigs run it and corrupt it, Bane knew that he had to smoke Batman out and when he did he knew that Batman would challenge him, but he also knew that Bruce Wayne would be the one to turn up dressed as Batman, so he beat him down but didn't kill him, he put him in the prison of the League Of Shadows to see if Bruce Wayne really could rise and become the Batman again to save Gotham, what he didn't take into account was that Bruce Wayne had had relations with Talia and wanted out of the crimefighting business. That's why Bane didn't blow Gotham up, he was merely a scare mongerer for the greater of good, he got the Dark Knight to Rise.

Comment: Do you have anything to back this, or is it just a theory?

Comment: The fact that Bane (IIRC) yells "Impossible!" when he sees the burning Bat-Symbol rather suggests that he *didn't* anticipate Batman returning.

Comment: This answer can have a vote for entertainment value alone - I'm in hysterics as to how thoroughly considered this wrong but highly likeable read on the character takes - Bane's highly convoluted but successful attempt to enable the Dark Knight to rise again - love it !